# How to enable Tabsets included while converting markdown document (.md) to .html document using pandoc command line code?

Tags: r-markdown, markdown, pandoc, file-conversion

My .rmd code is:

```
## Results {.tabset}

### Tab One

### Tab Two

## {-}
```

The conversion to markdown file (.md) is successfull. But, when I am trying to convert .md to .html using pandoc command code (**pandoc sample_readme.md -t html -o sample_readme.html**), the tabsets from .rmd are not migrated to html document. the html document is in the form of:

Results

Tab One

Tab Two